# How to fill a list collection from a database, by WPF combobox selection

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I have Many-to-Many Tables and want to display some of the fields in WPF controls.

[image]

How can I fill the list collection `List<Course> courses = new List<Course>()` whenever I select the InstructorIDs in the combobox ? I want to display only the CourseID and Title from the List in the ListView control

Here're my codes:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    SchoolEntities db = new SchoolEntities();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var instructors = db.Instructors.Where(f => f.HireDate == 2011).ToList();

        this.comboBox1.ItemsSource = instructors;
        this.comboBox1.DisplayMemberPath = "LastName";
        this.comboBox1.SelectedValuePath = "InstructorID";           
    }
    List<Course> courses = new List<Course>();

    private void comboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int S = (int)this.comboBox1.SelectedValue;
        var InstrSelection = db.Instructors.Include("CourseInstructors.Course").SingleOrDefault(f => f.InstructorID == S);


        foreach (var C in InstrSelection.CourseInstructors)
        {
            courses.Add(C.Course);
        }

        this.listView1.DataContext = null;
        this.listView1.DataContext = courses;
    }
}
```

And the window xaml

```
<Window x:Class="School.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="773" Width="677">

<Grid>        
    <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="comboBox1"  SelectionChanged="comboBox1_SelectionChanged"></ComboBox>
    <ListView  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="listView1">
        <ListView.View>
         <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header= "CourseID" />
            <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header= "Title" />                
         </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understand what you are asking. Are you just wondering why your current code is not displaying any courses in the ListView? If so then your problem is that you are setting the DataContext of the ListView when you should be setting the ItemsSource. You should likely also be clearing the list of courses before adding new ones:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    courses.Clear();
    ...

    this.listView1.ItemsSource = null; // ItemsSource instead of DataContext
    this.listView1.ItemsSource = courses;
}
```

### Edit

You will also have to add the DisplayMemberBindings to your GridViewColumns:

```
<GridViewColumn 
    Width="140" 
    Header="CourseID" 
    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CourseID}" /> <!-- Here -->
<GridViewColumn 
    Width="140" 
    Header="Title" 
    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Title}" /> <!-- And Here -->
```

Comment: Does the first part of my answer help then?

Comment: I used ItemSource and its displaying my namespace School.Course in the ListView columns. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I would make my parent data model contain a collection of the child data model, and bind the child `ComboBox` to the selected item in the parent `ComboBox`

For example, your `Instructor` model would contain

```
int InstructorId
string FirstName
string LastName
DateTime HireDate
List Courses
```

and you would bind your `ComboBox` of instructors to a `List<Instructor>`. Then you could bind your courses `ComboBox` to the instructor ComboBox's `SelectedItem.Courses`

```
<ComboBox x:Name="InstructorList" ... />

<ComboBox x:Name="CourseList"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=InstructorList, 
                                Path=SelectedItem.Courses}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Title"
          SelectedValuePath="CourseId" />
```